# Javascript convert timestamp

Tags: javascript, datetime, timestamp, date-formatting

I have a date in this format "2012-12-20 21:34:09".
How to format in the format `dd/mm/yyyy`

Answer (score 1):

You could try

```
var mydate = '2012-12-20 21:34:09';
var formatteddate = mydate.split(' ')[0].split('-').reverse().join('/');
```

Comment: @Nile, you really should not.. it is a valid answer.. just make a note that it not supported by all browsers (*it might in the future*)...

Comment: Oh, okay. well undeleted but still +1'd

Answer (score 1):

This should do it.

```
var date = new Date(Date.parse("2012-12-20 21:34:09"));
var converted = date.getDate() + "/" + (date.getMonth()+1) + "/" + date.getFullYear();
```

​**It's worthwhile to note that this will only work in Chrome and Opera.** (Thanks to Gaby aka G. Pertrioli)

Comment: @GabyakaG.Petrioli What do you mean?

Comment: `Date.parse('somestring')` and `new Date('somestring')` use the same parser so it still will not work... (*at least on my machine it fails.. does it actually work for you ?*)

Comment: @GabyakaG.Petrioli It even worked without the `Date.parse()`. I'm using Chrome

Answer (score 0):

You could parse the date and the reprint it. Something like this:

```
var date = new Date( Date.parse( "2012-12-20 21:34:09" ) );
var formattedDate = date.getDate() + "/" + ( date.getMonth() + 1 ) + "/" + date.getFullYear();
```

Comment: It's worthwhile to note that this will only work in Chrome and Opera.

Comment: Oh, well I tested it in Chrome before posting. Then I would suggest a RegEx approach but that have already been suggested. =)

Answer (score 0):

None of the other answers handle zero padding, which means that they won't fit the dd/mm/yyyy format for other dates.

```
var date = new Date("2012-12-20 21:34:09");

var converted = String("0" + date.getDate()).slice(-2);
converted += "/" + String("0" + date.getMonth()+1).slice(-2);
converted += "/" + date.getFullYear();

alert(converted);
```

**Edit**

cross-browser version:

```
var parts = "2012-12-20 21:34:09".split(" ")[0].split("-");

var converted = String("0" + parts[1]).slice(-2);
converted += "/" + String("0" + parts[2]).slice(-2);
converted += "/" + parts[0];

alert(converted);
```

Comment: It's worthwhile to note that this will only work in Chrome and Opera.

Answer (score 0):

using the power of RegExp it becomes quite simple:

```
"2012-12-20 21:34:09".replace(/^(\d+)-(\d+)-(\d+).*/, '$3/$2/$1');
```

returns `"20/12/2012"`